# Locating a stolen device

Tags: android, physical

Yesterday my friends Samsung Galaxy S3 was stolen. We have found the perpetrator but cannot yet prove anything. He is uploading photos to social media via the phone. Is there any chance to download and analyze the photo by some means to see from what device it was shot? What can we do in a circumstance such as this? The device also contains sensitive data. What can we do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could download the image and check the exif data. Some devices store the GPS co-ordinates as far as I know

Comment: Although, some social media sites strip EXIF information from the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Did you visit [Google Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)? If it is enabled, you can see the precise device location. Also geotags of the photos may help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://findmymobile.samsung.com/ and sign in using your Samsung account.

Comment: You obviously need to have registered the phone in advance, or otherwise have associated the device with yourself. What do you need to have done before the device was stolen?